# Setting up RabbitMq on VM in Azure

Tags: azure, rabbitmq

I am having issue setting up RabbitMq in Azure Virtual Machine. I have gone through the Market Place and installed the `RabbitMQ Cluster`. Azure has setup 3 VMs for me.

So when I log into one of the VM's using `putty` and enable rabbitMq management plugins I am faced with the following error:

> Error when reading /opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/.rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie: eacces

Initially I thought it was a permissions error so used the following command:

```
chmod 600 /opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/.rabbitmq/.erland.cookie
```

But came back with error file not found

> chmod: cannot access '/opt/bitnami/rabbitmq/.rabbitmq/.erland.cookie': No such file or directory

Am I missing something here?

This is my first time venturing into Azure so am still learning.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem. I was missing the `sudo` prefix

```
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

Which returned the following confirmation

The following plugins have been configured:

```
rabbitmq_management
rabbitmq_management_agent
rabbitmq_web_dispatch
```

Then I was able to setup the user account and permissions.

```
rabbitmqctl add_user test test
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags test administrator
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / test ".*" ".*" ".*"
```